# How can I change urlencode to python dictionary

Tags: python, django, urlencode

I have got data from POST like

```
first_name=jon&nick_name=harry
```

How can I change this to a python dictionary, like :

```
{
    "first_name":"jon",
    "nick_name":"harry"
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> urlparse.parse_qs("first_name=jon&nick_name=harry")
{'nick_name': ['harry'], 'first_name': ['jon']}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you trust that the URL arguments will always be properly formatted, this would be a minimal solution:

```
dict(pair.split("=") for pair in urlargs.split("&"))
```

In code that's going to be publicly accessible though, you'll probably want to use a library that does error checking. If you're using Django, you'll probably have access to them already in the dictionary-like object HttpRequest.POST.